# The compiler failed with error code 255

Tags: habitat

Running into this issue when I publish to IIS. 
I created a new feature module in my habitat/helix sitecore solution. Everything builds correctly in my gulp tasks but when the site is publish out to IIS it gets the following error.

```
Server Error in '/' Application. 

Compilation Error Description: An
 error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to
 service this request. Please review the following specific error
 details and modify your source code appropriately.  Compiler Error
 Message: The compiler failed with error code 255. 

 Show Detailed
 Compiler Output:
 c:\windows\system32\inetsrv>C:\websites\SiteName\Website\bin\roslyn\csc.exe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this issue while creating a new feature module. It turned out I had the wrong version for `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` compared to my other feature modules. Once I downgraded to the correct one it worked correctly

Comment: What was the original version and what version did you downgrade to?

Comment: @MichaelWest Original version was 2.0.0 and I downgraded to 1.0.8. 1.0.8 was the version that all the other features were referencing.